# App crashes when refreshing table (Probably the call endUpdates on tableView causes the crash)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Came across this post but did not fix my problem.

[iPhone app crashing on [self.tableView endUpdates]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594566/iphone-app-crashing-on-self-tableview-endupdates)

Having a `UITableView` which `loads` articles from a newspaper website. First `load` works 
as expected but when I use an `UIRefreshControl` to `fetch` the articles again my app crashes
when (`animating`) `inserting` `rows`.

Error:

[image]

**Code:**

```
- (void)insertRowsWithAnimation
{
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSInteger i = self.latestArticlesArray.count - self.latestArticlesArray.count;

    for (NSDictionary *dict in self.latestArticlesArray) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        i++;
    }
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)fetchEntries
{
    UIView *currentTitleView = [[self navigationItem] titleView];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *aiView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

    [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:aiView];
    [aiView startAnimating];

    void (^completionBlock) (NSArray *array, NSError *err) = ^(NSArray *array, NSError *err) {
        if (!err) {
            [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:currentTitleView];
            self.latestArticlesArray = [NSArray array];
            self.latestArticlesArray = array;
            [self insertRowsWithAnimation];
        }
    };
    [[Store sharedStore] fetchArticlesWithCompletion:completionBlock];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.latestArticlesArray.count;
}
```

If you want to see more methods please let me know. Hope you can help. From what I've learned so far I think the number of posts have changed therefore the table expects another amount of articles to show?

Comment: post your numberOfRowsInSection: method. the error usually happens because you have called insertRow but are not changing the number of rows returned in this method

Comment: See my post, I'm just giving back the `count`, do I have to refresh the `latesArticlesArray` somehow in this `method`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
NSInteger i = self.latestArticlesArray.count - self.latestArticlesArray.count;
```

sets `i` to ***zero***, therefore `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` is called with an empty array.

I assume that your intention was to call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` with the row numbers of the newly added rows, but then you have to remember the old data before replacing the array in

```
self.latestArticlesArray = array;
```

But note that since you replace the entire array, you can as well call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

instead of `beginUpdates`/`insertRowsAtIndexPaths`/`endUpdates`.

---

*Update:* My first analysis is wrong (and wattson12's is correct). As you said in the comments, you need just a simple animation that removes all previous rows and inserts the new rows after a fetch. This can be done like this:

```
- (void)replaceArticlesWithAnimation:(NSArray *)articles
{
    NSUInteger oldCount = [self.latestArticlesArray count];
    self.latestArticlesArray = articles;
    NSUInteger newCount = [self.latestArticlesArray count];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < oldCount; i++) {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < newCount; i++) {
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

and in `fetchEntries` you call

```
if (!err) {
    [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:currentTitleView];
    [self replaceArticlesWithAnimation:array];
}
```

Comment: Calling `reloadData` kills the whole animation of `inserting rows`. I know it looks strange setting the `NSInteger` to 0 but it works for some reason. As mentioned in my original post the very first load works and I see that `rows` gets inserted in an `animated way` but not when I call the `method` again. Any other idea?

Comment: @McClane: I see now that I did not analyze your code correctly, I think that wattson12 is correct.

Comment: @McClane: For a perfect animated update, you have to *compare* the old and new array, call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` for deleted articles and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` for new articles.

Comment: @McClane: If the first fetch loads articles A, B, C, D, E and the next fetch articles C, D, E, F, G, then you would call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` for rows 0 and 1, and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` for rows 3, 4, to get the correct animation.

Comment: first of all thanks for helping me. My reload of articles is not that complicated (yet). I just load the latest 100 articles. There is no A B C article, I just want to show the latest 100 articles so the response I get is always 100 objects (the latest). I do not refer to any published date or something like that.

Comment: @McClane: So what kind of animation do you expect if a new set of 100 articles has been loaded?

Comment: exactly the same as with the very first fetch (I'd be fine with just delete all what's showing and re-load everything). Also tried to delete all rows first when refreshing the table but the same crash occurred.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26807/discussion-between-martin-r-and-mcclane)

Answer (score 2):

The reason it loads the first time is because you are inserting a number of rows each time, so on the first run the number of rows changes from 0 to the count in array (in the completion block), and you call insertRows with a number of index paths equal to the count of the array.

The 2nd time you call it you are inserting new rows, but you are not updating the count to reflect the new sum. You should be adding your existing array to the one returned in the completion block, and returning the count of that combined array in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: I do assign the `array` returned from the `block` to the `array` I use in the `method` `numberOfRowsInSection`. See `call` in the `fetchEntries` `block`: `self.latestArticlesArray = array;`

Comment: @McClane: If you call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` with 5 row numbers, than the table view assumes that the table has 5 rows *more than before*.

Comment: @Martin, I'm confused, why 5? I'm just giving the the updated `self.latestArticlesArray` I got from the `completion block` to the method for inserting the rows. But how does this work in detail? Does the method only tries/wants to insert NEW data or does the method just re-adds all?

Comment: @McClane: Assume that the first fetch loads 3 objects to `self.latestArticlesArray`. Then the next fetch loads 5 objects. You *replace* the array, so that `self.latestArticlesArray` contains 5 objects now. Then you call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` with 5 rows, therefore the table view assumes that the table has 3 + 5 = 8 objects.

Comment: @Martin, my `call` to the newspaper API is limited, whenever I `call` `fetchEntries` the limit is set to 100 articles so I always get back 100 `objects`. So actually I cannot have different amounts of `objects` with several `fetchEntries calls`.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for explaining that a bit clearer. mcclane, try logging the latest articles array count in number of rows, and logging the count of the indexPaths array when you insert rows, you should see the mismatch there as you run the code more than once

Answer (score 1):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
    });
```

Comment: Put [self.tableView endUpdates] in the dispach_async block. This updates the UI in the main queue asynchronously. using this solved my problem. Hope will work for you.